# How to extend C++ classes from Terralang?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to embed [terralang](http://terralang.org/) into a C++ application, such that C++ classes can be extended *from terra*, including *overloading virtual functions*?

BONUS: Can this be done (semi?)automatically for a (large)set of classes, without needing to write "wrapper code" for each class and each virtual method?

Comment: https://github.com/zdevito/terra/issues/46, "C++ Support" -> "It's something that would be good to have but we don't have any plans to do it at the moment because of the complexity involved" ?

Comment: SWIG support Lua; could that be used somehow?

Comment: To be honest, I learned about `terralang` from this question. It made me curious, so I did dig a little and this is what I found. Anyway, I think you could also ask also on `terralang`'s Github.